# Can micro-USB android device (Redmi 4 (India)) be charged using a hybrid converter (USB type-C to type-A) with MacBook Pro high watt charger?

Tags: usb, charging

I have MacBook Pro (15'', 2017 model). It comes with a very high voltage charger with USB type-C port. I have a hybrid converter (USB Type-C to VGA + USB Type-C + USB Type-A). I want to charge my Redmi 4 (India variant) device using a cable (USB Type-A to micro-USB). My phone supports unspecified version of Qualcomm quick charge (tested with a turbo-charger of Moto Phone).

So, the connection is as given below:
`MacBook Pro Charger` -> `USB Type-C to USB Type-C cable` -> `USB Type-C to Hybrid output converter including USB Type-A` -> `USB Type-A to micro-USB cable` -> `Redmi 4 device`.

Will above configuration damage my phone or charger? Also, will my phone be able to charge quickly as it supports unspecified version of Qualcomm quick charge?

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not damage your phone.

Whether or not it will charge quickly depends on the specific kind of hybrid converter you have. Most likely it will not charge quickly, as the USB Type-A port is most commonly just at 500 mA, or 900 mA for some ports that USB 3.0. It is not common to see dedicated charging ports with higher amps in such hybrid converters.